# MongoDb Average last 24 hour docs with an interval of 1 hour?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, aggregate

I want an average of Temperature in the last 24 hour docs,[Single Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs9wa.png) with interval of 1 hour, so i will be expecting 24 hour docs in the end

Answer (score -1):

```
db.database.aggregate(
   [
   {
       $match:
        { 'time':
          { $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) }
         } 
    },
     {
       $group:
         {
           avgTempreture: { $avg: "$Tempreture" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```